# What evidences this technique of visualizing different color words in sequence, to help you sleep?

Tags: sleep

What's this [technique](https://old.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/259w7p/mysleepbutton_a_new_app_that_could_help_you_fall/chf5yi8/) called? Any evidence?

> I'll make it easier. Visualize the word Red. In big red letters. Examine your creation but don't judge harshly. After a few seconds, switch to the word Blue, in blue letters. Then again with Green. Now repeat the sequence or feel free to wander off into any pattern of colors.
>
> This is how it works. You can't think and feel at the same time (by feeling I mean any of the senses including vision) so exercising your vision causes your brain to shut down. You can do the same by listening intently, etc.
>
> This has usefulness beyond relaxing enough to fall asleep. I have a theory that high level problem solving requires switching to feelings. We feel our way through tough problems because conventional thinking is too tedious, inefficient.
>
> BTW, you now know how to meditate.

Comment: Seems like a very anecdotal comment. You might be better off asking the person who wrote it?

Comment: Or ask the question to the Skeptics community, this sounds like neuro-BS to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Imagery Distraction**

The technique referred to is called 'imagery distraction' (Harvey & Payne, 2002).

Some evidence has been found for “imagery distraction” being associated with shorter sleep onset latency and less frequent and distressing pre-sleep cognitive activity.

> The success of the “imagery distraction” task is attributed to it occupying sufficient “cognitive space” to keep the individual from re-engaging with thoughts, worries, and concerns during the pre-sleep period.

The type of imagery seems less important.  So visualizing coloured words should be equally as effective as counting sheep.

Harvey, A. G., & Payne, S. (2002). The management of unwanted pre-sleep thoughts in insomnia: distraction with imagery versus general distraction. Behaviour Research and Therapy, 40(3), 267–277. doi:10.1016/s0005-7967(01)00012-2

Comment: So basically the only correct part of the description is "Visualize"?

Comment: Yes.  Impressive how pseudoscience can rebadge and market something as simple as counting sheep.